# How to use date-picker plugin in ionic 3

Tags: angular, datepicker, ionic3, bootstrap-4

I know its a very simple question. But since the  [date-picker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/date-picker/) documentation
  is not clear on how to implement this in html I'm asking this question.

somePage.ts code

```
var changeTime = this.datePicker.show({
  date: new Date(),
  mode: 'time',
}).then(
  date => console.log('Got date: ', date),
  err => console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)
);
```

Html Code

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="changeTime" name="changeTime"></ion-input>
```

Expectation : A dropdown for changing time(HH:MM) and it is for the desktop
  View.

Answer (score 0):

The [native datepicker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/date-picker/) is for the cordova plugin so it works only after installing the plugin `cordova-plugin-datepicker` and by launching the app in a mobile os.

if you want to use a datepicker for html and works with browser and all platform go for [the datepicker component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: The datepicker component is having the mobile popup view but we need a simple calendar kinda view here. Any pointers?

Comment: in this case you can choose an angular component/directive which fit your needs: eg: https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker